# How to preserve the leading zero when changing a string into a number using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

How do I convert a string such as `"03"` into a number and keep the zero at the beginning of the string? Using `Number("03")` will remove the leading `0` and return 3, but I want to keep the `0` there. How would I go about doing this?

Here's my JS function for context:

```js
function format(input, unit) {
  if (new RegExp(unit, 'i').test('minute second')) {
    if (String(input).length === 1) return Number(`0${input}`);
    else return input;
  }
  else if (unit === 'hour') {
    return input;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**: What I got so far

```js
let timer = {
  hours: 0,
  minutes: 1,
  seconds: 30,
  updateTimerDisplay() {
    document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = this.hour;
    document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML = String(format(this.minutes, 'minute'));
    document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = String(format(this.seconds, 'second'));
  },
  startTimer() {
    const { updateTimerDisplay: updateDisplay } = this;
    let update = setInterval(_ => {
      this.seconds -= 1;
      if (this.seconds < 0) {
        this.seconds = 59;
        this.minutes -= 1;
      }
      if (this.minutes < 0) {
        this.minutes = 59;
        this.hours -= 1;
      }
      updateDisplay();
    }, 1000);
  }
};
timer.updateTimerDisplay();
timer.startTimer();

function format(input, unit) {
  if (new RegExp(unit, 'i').test('minute second')) {
    if (String(input).length === 1) return `0${input}`;
    else return String(input);
  }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript numbers don't have leading zeros? May I ask what is the reason you need the leading zero?

Comment: A number is a number, not a string. To see a leading zero, or even its decimal representation, is always a process of turning it back to a string.

Comment: @evolutionxbox It is for a timer thing, I want to be able to add zeroes to the beginning of the minutes and seconds like a clock should.

Comment: In that case you are talking about a string, not a number.

Comment: May you provide a [mcve] of how you expect to use it? Maybe what you've done so far?

Comment: Why then you do not use a number and then convert it to `string` it for representation? You can provide more code so that we could help you with the solution.

Comment: Html timers use padded strings to display time

Comment: @evolutionxbox I updated my question :D

Comment: If `format` is only ever being used for output, then don't convert it back to a number

Comment: There are probably other ways to do this, but if there is a way to preserve the leading zero then that would probably be the best way for me

Comment: As others have mentioned already, numbers and strings are seperate. A number only stores whatever it needs to represent a number. `00003243` is not a number. But if you really want to store the information about whether the number had a leading zero or not. You could divide the number by `100`, thus resulting in a decimal number which keeps the leading 0. But as mentioned, this is not the proper way to do this

Comment: ``String(this.minutes).length === 1 ? `0${this.minutes}` : this.minutes;`` Came up with this

Comment: Thanks for all the help :D

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- Spelling of `this.hour`: should be `this.hours`
- By calling `updateDisplay` you don't pass on the expected value for `this`. It is better to just keep the original name of the method, and use `this.updateTimerDisplay`.
- Don't convert the 0-prefixed string back to number: you are interested in something to *display*, so keep the string format.

Without changing too much else in your code, the above corrections make it work:

```js
let timer = {
  hours: 0,
  minutes: 1,
  seconds: 30,
  updateTimerDisplay() {
    // Use textContent, not innerHTML (that is for HTML content)
    document.getElementById('hour').textContent = this.hours; // spelling!
    // The function format returns a string, so no need to call String on it:
    document.getElementById('minute').textContent = format(this.minutes, 'minute');
    document.getElementById('second').textContent = format(this.seconds, 'second');
  },
  startTimer() {
    // Don't read a function reference into a variable, as you'll lose the this-binding
    // --------- const { updateTimerDisplay: updateDisplay } = this;
    let update = setInterval(_ => {
      this.seconds -= 1;
      if (this.seconds < 0) {
        this.seconds = 59;
        this.minutes -= 1;
      }
      if (this.minutes < 0) {
        this.minutes = 59;
        this.hours -= 1;
      }
      // By having `this.` here, you pass that this-reference to the function
      this.updateTimerDisplay();
    }, 1000);
  }
};
timer.updateTimerDisplay();
timer.startTimer();

function format(input, unit) {
  // RegExp is overkill here. Just use includes:
  if (['minute', 'second'].includes(unit.toLowerCase())) {
    // Don't convert with Number: it must be a string:
    if (String(input).length === 1) return `0${input}`;
    else return String(input);
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="hour"></span>:<span id="minute"></span>:<span id="second"></span>
```